# Como é o ciclo de vida de uma aplicação ASP.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Essa é uma dúvida que eu sempre tive (inclusive em versões anteriores do ASP.NET), mas vou perguntar aqui no contexto do ASP.NET 5. A dúvida é a seguinte: ao construir uma aplicação com ASP.NET 5 codificamos uma classe `Startup` que é responsável por configurar a pipeline com um método `Configure`. Qualquer coisa relativa a inicialização da aplicação web é feita ali.

É exatamente aí que está minha dúvida: o conceito de inicialização da aplicação web. Uma aplicação web não faz nada por si propria, ela espera requisições para fazer. A duvida é: feita uma requisição a aplicação é inicializada, recebe a requisição, envia a resposta e finaliza? Ou ela é inicializada caso não esteja, processa a requisição, responde e fica a espera de novas requisições?

Como funciona esse conceito de inicialização para uma aplicação web ASP.NET 5? Caso realmente ela seja inicializada caso não esteja e fique esperando requisições novas, como isso funciona realmente?

Fiz um teste pra ver se entendia melhor o que está acontecendo da seguinte forma: criei uma classe singleton `Exemplo` que tem uma propriedade `DataInstanciado`. Depois disso criei um controller `ExemploController` da seguinte forma:

```
public class ExemploController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("/api/instancia")]
    public Exemplo GetInstancia()
    {
        return Exemplo.ObtemInstancia();
    }
}
```

Ao enviar uma requisição para "/api/instancia" recebi um objeto contendo um datetime que é a data da criação do objeto. Em requisições posteriores o objeto retornado foi exatamente o mesmo, com a mesma data. Passados então 30 minutos, ao requisitar novamente o objeto retornado foi outro, com a data de 30 minutos depois.

Dessa forma, o servidor parece que está mantendo a aplicação rodando. Parece que fica na memória os objetos. Mas não estou entendendo como isso funciona. Como funciona o ciclo de vida desse tipo de aplicação?

**EDIÇÃO**: Eu sei que existe um ciclo de vida de uma aplicação rodando no IIS, mas não é especificamente do IIS que eu estou perguntando. As aplicações ASP.NET 5 usam a especificação OWIN e, portanto, podem ser hospedadas não só no IIS, mas de outras formas também (como self host). O que eu queria saber é como funciona o ciclo de vida, independente de onde a aplicação é hospedada.

Comment: Acredito que isto seja o tempo de sessão do servidor e não o lifecycle do asp.net.

Comment: Eu pensei mesmo que tivesse alguma relação com sessão, então pra testar botei no controller antes do return a linha `this.Context.Session.Clear()` e então passei a receber o erro "InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request." de forma que aparentemente o uso de sessões nem é configurado por padrão.

Comment: vê se isso ajuda https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: @kabstergo, ajuda um pouco, mas isso aí é em relação ao IIS especificamente. O ASP.NET 5 usa a especificação OWIN, daí o ciclo de vida não deve ser ligado diretamente ao servidor. Você sabe se tem algo parecido para o ASP.NET 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**OWIN**

> OWIN define um padrão entre servidores .NET e aplicações WEB. O Objetivo do OWIN é desacoplar o servidor e a aplicação, e encorajar o desenvolvimento de módulos simples para uma aplicação Web em .NET.

http://owin.org/

O Owin não força a especificação de um ciclo de vida de uma aplicação Web, mas sim o desenvolvimento e utilização de [Microserviços](http://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html) que podem ser injetados na aplicação.

**Ciclo de Vida**

O ciclo de vida de aplicações Web em ASP NET 5 é totalmente dependente da aplicação que carrega a mesma (basicamente um projeto ASP NET 5 é uma biblioteca que implementa uma especificação).

Pontos importantes:

1. Ela permanece em memória
2. Ela possui uma inicialização
3. Pode ser finalizada à qualquer momento (IIS, Weblistener, codegen, etc).

**Ciclo de vida do IIS**

No caso do IIS (e também o IIS Express) você precisa apontar o diretório onde está sua aplicação Web e então iniciá-la. Este processo faz com que:

1. O IIS escute a porta especificada no servidor (80, 8080, 443, etc..)
2. Carregue seu projeto (DLL's) e suas configurações (web.config)
3. Execute um código interno para inicializar sua aplicação

A cada requisição feita ao servidor o IIS atribui a resposta baseado na implementação do seu código (que sempre está carregado em memória). Este é o motivo pelo qual a data (vinda de uma classe singleton) ser sempre a mesma:

```
public class ExemploController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("/api/instancia")]
    public Exemplo GetInstancia()
    {
        return Exemplo.ObtemInstancia();
    }
}
```

Você pode estudar mais à fundo sobre o ciclo de vida de uma aplicação IIS [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) (está em inglês).

**Ciclo de vida ASP NET 5 (IIS, Web Listener, etc)**

Nesses casos, para trabalhar sobre o mesmo conceito de ciclo de vida anteriores o conceito é basicamente o mesmo do IIS:

1. Escutar uma porta específica.
2. Inicializar sua aplicação através da descoberta da classe `Startup`
3. Atribuir respostas baseadas nos `middlewares` registrados.

Talvez fique mais fácil entender por este diagrama:

[image: Ciclo de vida ASP NET 5]
*Este diagrama é abstrato, não representa oficialmente o ciclo de vida desenvolvido pela Microsoft.*

**Ok, minha aplicação permanece em memória, mas e sobre o MVC?**

O Mvc, em aplicações ASP NET 5, é um serviço (middleware) que atende requisições e atribui respostas baseadas no processamento de controladores (selecionadas à partir da URL). O `middleware` MVC, tal como todos os outros estará sempre em memória, registrado em uma lista.

Porém este serviço (persistente) cria uma `Controller` (transiente) para toda requisição Http.

então, códigos como este vão sempre mostrar novos valores:

```
public class ApiController
{
    [HttpGet("api/date/")]
    public DateTime GetDate()
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

> Passados então 30 minutos, ao requisitar novamente o objeto retornado foi outro, com a data de 30 minutos depois.

Há um motivo bem simples para isto acontecer:

https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc753179%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

O IIS possui uma "reciclagem de memória", se sua aplicação fica inativa por muito tempo ele simplesmente remove a aplicação da memória (ele vai iniciá-la novamente quando uma nova requisição surgir).